# Converting RDD(Arrary(String,Int) ) into Json in scala

Tags: json, scala, rdd

I have a RDD of form:
Array((A,3), (B,5), (C,88))

I want to convert into json in scala like

{
"A":3,
"B":5,
"C":88,
}

Comment: What version of spark are you using? Can you convert this RDD to DF? That would make your life easier. But the requirement is only RDD then you might want to try json4s or similar to that

Comment: Spark 1.6 .. ya i tried using toDF() but its not working

Comment: One more thing if we convert it to DF , we will get something like {"_1":"A","_2":3}
{"_1":"B","_2":5}
{"_1":"C","_2":88}
Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: val x: Array[(String, Int)] = Array(("A",3), ("B",5), ("C",88))
  val distData: RDD[(String, Int)] = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(x)
  val df: DataFrame = sparkSession.sqlContext.createDataFrame(distData)
  df.write.json("resources/myJson.json")

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `RDD[Array[Tuple2[String, Int]]]` as

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(Array(("A",3), ("B",5), ("C",88))))
```

then you can do the following to get the `json` format you want

```
val columnName = rdd.map(x => x.map(_._1)).first().toSeq
rdd.map(x => x.map(_._2)).map(arr => (arr(0), arr(1), arr(2))).toDF(columnName:_*).toJSON.foreach(x => println(x.toString))
```

which should give you

```
{"A":3,"B":5,"C":88}
```

Comment: What if i want to print only String value . like : A ,B,C

Comment: You mean to say you want to filter only A, B, C only? please clarify. @HemantKumar

Comment: what do you want to filter? You can filter in dataframe level. :) there is .filter api

Comment: So , I have to convert it into Dataframe

Comment: `rdd.map(x => x.map(_._2)).map(arr => (arr(0), arr(1), arr(2))).toDF(columnName:_*)` in my answer is a dataframe already :)